# Using dropdown button together with tooltip causes a JavaScript error in BS 5

Tags: bootstrap-5, twitter-bootstrap-tooltip

when using a dropdown button together with a tooltip throws a JavaScript error in Bootstrap 5. Please run this snippet:

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <div class="btn-group">
      <button id="btnFingerprints" type="button" class="btn btn-circle btn-secondary me-2 dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle-second="tooltip" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false" title="Testing">
          <i class="ti-exchange-vertical"></i>
      </button>

      <div class="dropdown-menu">
        <button class="dropdown-item" type="button" id="btnBajarHuellas">
            <i class="ti-download me-2"></i>Bajar huellas
        </button>
        
        <button class="dropdown-item" type="button" id="btnSubirHuellas">
            <i class="ti-upload me-2"></i>Subir huellas
        </button>
      </div>

      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script>
let tooltipTriggerList = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle-second="tooltip"]'))
    tooltipTriggerList.map(function (tooltipTriggerEl) {
        return new bootstrap.Tooltip(tooltipTriggerEl)
    })
</script>
```

Some points to consider here:

- data-bs-toggle is already used to allow the button to have a dropdown, so I have created a data-bs-toggle-second attribute.
- This button is not created when the page loads. It is created by an ajax call which refreshes a DIV so I think I should instantiate the tooltip manually since the data attribute is not the standard. For the data-bs-toggle attribute I don't need to call anything from Bootstrap since that attribute is the standard.

How can I do that?

Thanks

Jaime

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bootstrap doesn't allow more than one instance per element, so the solution is simple, just wrap the button inside a container that contains the tooltip:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
  integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="btn-group">
  <div data-bs-toggle-second="tooltip" title="Testing">
    <button id="btnFingerprints" type="button" class="btn btn-circle btn-secondary me-2 dropdown-toggle"
      data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
      <i class="ti-exchange-vertical"></i>
    </button>

    <div class="dropdown-menu">
      <button class="dropdown-item" type="button" id="btnBajarHuellas">
        <i class="ti-download me-2"></i>Bajar huellas
      </button>

      <button class="dropdown-item" type="button" id="btnSubirHuellas">
        <i class="ti-upload me-2"></i>Subir huellas
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
  integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script>
  let tooltipTriggerList = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle-second="tooltip"]'))
  tooltipTriggerList.map(function (tooltipTriggerEl) {
    return new bootstrap.Tooltip(tooltipTriggerEl)
  })
</script>
```